# Store byte array and string in same file

Tags: java, android, arrays

Earlier I was storing only string in my file which can be store in SD card now I would to store byte[] also in same files. So do I just need to store normal to the file like this:

for string:- `bufferWritter.write(data);`
for bytes:- `FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("pathname"), myByteArray)`
or `fos.write(myByteArray);`

So if I do like that then how can I differ message whether it is string or byte[].

Even I would like to know that is this is a good way to do?

Comment: It is not very clean, in my opinion. Could you clarify your purpose ?

Comment: I need to store messages which can be a normal string or a image(which is converted into byte array) in a same file.

Comment: @TinTran And one more thing i need to send this file to server(If i am not sending the images to the server so i may only store the image path in my file and store image in my local storage).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write some sort of header to your file which should state what it does represent.
If you have multiple items in one file, also specify the length of the data parts.

> [byte] sort of data (0=String, 1=Image)
>
> And then the actual data.

But I would recommend you use a different format like json or make a serializable object.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a try to some **JSON** implementation (maybe GSON? or some alternative) so you can have stored mixed data types in one file or write your own de/**serialization** routine so you can store whole objects.

*Note:* if you implement Serializable interface by a class that represent object to be stored, don't forget to re-generate UUID each time you change contents of that class, it will save you some time figuring out what went wrong